# Connecting Application to Database: Problems with SQL Server Native Client 11.0

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, database-connection, connection-string

Our application uses the Microsoft Data Link Properties dialog to create connection strings.  This has worked swimmingly well for us, as it means that we can stay on top of new providers as they are introduced.  However, we have found a very odd problem, which can only be traced to the connection string.

**Details**

The connection string for SQL Server Native Client 11.0 acts erratically, but the connection string for Microsoft OLE DB is rock-solid.

Using the following examples:

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=SQLUserPW;Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=SQLUser;Initial Catalog=SQLClientDB;Data Source=SQLClientServer
```

SQL Server Native Client 11.0

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security="";Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=SQLUser;Initial Catalog=SQLClientDB;Data Source=SQLClientServer;
Initial File Name="";Server SPN=""
```

(Here's an aside - even through I indicate in the Data Link Properties dialog that the password isn't a `Blank password`, and we always `Allow saving password`, the connection string is ALWAYS created without a password, and with `Persist Security Info=False` -- I manually change the resulting connection string to match what is below:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Password=SQLUserPW;Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=SQLUser;Initial Catalog=SQLClientDB;Data Source=SQLClientServer
```

)

**Problem**

Now, here's the rub.  Until today, we have treated these two particular SQL Providers as equal.  Some clients have one, some have the other, and our system treats neither one better than the other.  The system behaves normally, except in one place where we are calling a stored procedure via an ADODB.Command.  **IF** we use the Native client, the command returns no data, and the below is logged to the server's Application Event Log:

```
Login failed for user 'SQLUser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine> ]
Log Name: Application
Source: MSSQLSERVER
Event ID: 18456
Task Category: Login
Level: Information
Keywords: Classic,Audit Failure
```

Is there something about how the Users and Logins are configured on SQL server which could explain why the providers are behaving differently in this place?  We have other EXEC calls that return fine, and so far this is the only instance we've seen where the providers differ.

Comment: make sure a connection is open before exec a stored proc

Comment: Thank you, @CPMunich, but the only difference in the application is the connection string being offered.  If the Microsoft OLE connection string is used, the function works correctly.  This means that the connection is open and functional before the exec call.

Comment: and why you are getting an "Login failed" message if the Connection is open? I will test this in my environment tomorrow because I am changing vom SQLOLEDB to SQLNCLI11 also.

Comment: Yes, @CPMunich, that is exactly my question.  I have confirmed multiple times that the user ID and password are correct in both cases.  I am wondering if the Native Client 11 does more to confirm the credentials of the user than the OLE provider does.  Is it possible that they have configured the database in such a way that the Native Client fails the authentication, where the OLE DB client succeeds?

Comment: I use the same Connection string for OLEDB and Native Client and it works - except for the provider attribute. You could try to single or double quote your password and or UserID. Example: PWD='SQLUserPW';UID='SQLUser';  by the way: it is highly recommended to set the attribute "Persist Security Info" to false for security